# Real-time plot does not show up

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, real-time

I am plotting sensor data from FTDI port using `plt.plot()` from `pyplot`. Unfortunately I don't see a line for some reason. However when I change mark type: `plt.plot(duration, temp, 'o')` (or to any other point-like marktype) everything goes as it should. I was trying to increase sleep time (reading problems with `plot` and live-plotting from other similar questions) but that was not the case.
(I am using Ubuntu 14.04 if that is the case for some reason)

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print "We are plotting sonar values"
f = open('/dev/ttyUSB0', 'r')

plt.axis()
plt.ion()
plt.show()
duration = 0;
while True:
    print f.readline()
    temp = f.readline()

    temp = int(temp[1:])
    plt.plot(duration, temp, 'o')
    duration+=1
    plt.draw()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: StackOverflow Netiquette encourages Question authors to post also a MCVE -- a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example -- for a problem you ask to get help for. Try to re-edit your post in this direction.

Comment: Check the .show() before plotting + live-plotting from other threads is to be done via a shared Object?

Comment: I mean 'other similar questions', edited this. What you mean by checking the .show()? Tried to plot the first point before the loop, not helped.

Comment: Maxim, may be this >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/26268733/3666197 and this >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/25769600/3666197 may help you for a fast GUI within a real-time control-loop constraints.