# Plotting data in real time

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython

I have a program which outputs to the terminal a number, one line at a time.
My goal is to have something else read these numbers and graph them in a line plot in real time. matplotlib and wxpython have been suggested, but I'm not sure how to go about implementing these.

Comment: Where will output be rendered?  Web page?

Comment: It can be on any old interface that can be viewed from the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like this library for HTML5 graphing.  Here is demo of real time updates: http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/dynamic-update

Are you simply asking for recommendations on plotting libs?

Comment: Something like what you linked, except rather than random data, it would plot the numbers being output line by line in real time. I was thinking of using a pipe:./output | python graph.py

Comment: Would be pretty easy to alter that JS code to read from a file you are piping output to.  (note the link to view that demo in jsFiddle)  Main distinction I think being this is a 'web' solution and I am still unclear if that is what you desire.  That said if your criteria is "It can be on any old interface that can be viewed from the desktop" I suppose it could fit.

Comment: Is there a way to have it be viewed as an application?

Comment: What type of application?  You develop in Python?  A little lost.  Talk of 'desktop' makes me think we are talking Windows?  What language you envisioning the application being written in?

Comment: The program outputting the numbers is for linux on a red hat server (I'm using tightvnc). Doesn't matter what the application is written in, but if ./program | python graph.py could yield a graph plotting program's numbers in real time, then that would be great. Is there a way to view the jsFiddle's demo by, let's say, calling it from the terminal? My knowledge is limited for this, sorry :/

Comment: Running a server like httpd/apache on your RHEL box you could view the data with a web browser from any remote machine over the Internet.  Wondering a little now what this data is.  You familiar with exiting tools like nagios/cacti?

Comment: The data is simply numbers in this format:
100 \n
1000 \n
11 \n
etc. And I'm not at all familiar with them.

Answer (score 1):

See the following links:

- [What is the best real time plotting widget for wxPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457246/what-is-the-best-real-time-plotting-widget-for-wxpython)
- [Minimalistic Real-Time Plotting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401857/minimalistic-real-time-plotting-in-python)
- http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis/
- http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/real-time-data-plots-td2344816.html

As some of those point out, you might be able to use wx's PyPlot for something really simple or use Chaco.