# Real time plotting of serial data with python and tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, multiprocessing, pyserial

I have been working for some time to find a way to graph incoming data from an arduino with a Python GUI. I was able to accomplish this using the Matplotlib animation function to read in 6 different variables and plot 4 of them 2 on one subplot 2 on another subplot. This was able to be done fast enough that it was graphing real time (20 samples per second).

I now need to modify the system to read in 12 different variables at the same time of which 8 are graphed. 4 on one sub plot 4 on another at the same rate of 20 samples per second. I haven't been able to get this to work and have tried a few different things and done a lot of research but can't seem to figure out how to do it with my limited knowledge of python. Im not very familiar with multiprocessing or multithreading but they seem to be the way that people are able to speed up the graphing process. I know that the matplotlib animated function itself is threaded so I'm not sure how much the threading would help with that or if there's a way to read in one thread and update the graph in another. I'm operating at the highest baudrate that the arduino supports 250000. I also was able to find an example where someone was able to get a very high speed plot in this post but havent been able to modify to work for my use: [What is the best real time plotting widget for wxPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457246/what-is-the-best-real-time-plotting-widget-for-wxpython)

the data is received from the arduino like this:

integer.integer.integer|integer.integer.integer|integer.integer.integer|integer.integer.integer

where the pipe represents a new actuator (what each variable im sending is coming from)

I'm fairly new to python so sorry if this isnt so pythonic but here are two examples I have: 
This is a gui using the animation function:

```
import Tkinter
import serial
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from collections import deque
import random

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.arduinoData = serial.Serial('com5', 250000)#115200)

        frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)

        self.running = False
        self.ani = None

        self.start = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Start", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.start.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.run = Tkinter.Button(self.start, text="RUN", bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.getData)
        self.run.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.stop_frame = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="STOP", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10 )
        self.stop_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.stop = Tkinter.Button(self.stop_frame, text="STOP", bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.stopTest)
        self.stop.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.fig = plt.Figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(211)
        self.line0, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line1, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line2, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line3, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(212)
        self.line4, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line5, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line6, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line7, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,master=master)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=4, padx=20, pady=20)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

    def getData(self):
        if self.ani is None:
            self.k = 0
            self.arduinoData.flushInput()
            self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
            return self.start()
        else:
            self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
            self.arduinoData.flushInput()
            self.ani.event_source.start()
        self.running = not self.running

    def stopTest(self):
        self.arduinoData.write("<H>")
        if self.running:
            self.ani.event_source.stop()
        self.running = not self.running

    def resetTest(self):
        self.k = 0
        self.xdata = []
        self.pressure1 = []
        self.displacement1 = []
        self.cycle1 = []
        self.pressure2 = []
        self.displacement2 = []
        self.cycle2 = []
        self.pressure3 = []
        self.displacement3 = []
        self.cycle3 = []
        self.pressure4 = []
        self.displacement4 = []
        self.cycle4 = []
        self.line1.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata1)
        self.line2.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata2)
        self.ax1.set_ylim(0,1)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(0,1)
        self.ax2.set_ylim(0,1)
        self.ax2.set_xlim(0,1)

    def start(self):
        self.xdata = []
        self.pressure1 = []
        self.displacement1 = []
        self.cycle1 = []
        self.pressure2 = []
        self.displacement2 = []
        self.cycle2 = []
        self.pressure3 = []
        self.displacement3 = []
        self.cycle3 = []
        self.pressure4 = []
        self.displacement4 = []
        self.cycle4 = []
        self.k = 0
        self.arduinoData.flushInput()
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
            self.fig,
            self.update_graph,
            interval=1,
            repeat=True)
        self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
        self.running = True
        self.ani._start()

    def update_graph(self, i):
        self.xdata.append(self.k)
        while (self.arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
            pass
        x = self.arduinoData.readline()
        strip_data = x.strip()
        split_data = x.split("|")
        actuator1 = split_data[0].split(".")
        actuator2 = split_data[1].split(".")
        actuator3 = split_data[2].split(".")
        actuator4 = split_data[3].split(".")
        self.pressure1.append(int(actuator1[0]))
        self.displacement1.append(int(actuator1[1]))
        self.cycle1 = int(actuator1[2])
        self.pressure2.append(int(actuator2[0]))
        self.displacement2.append(int(actuator2[1]))
        self.cycle2 = int(actuator2[2])
        self.pressure3.append(int(actuator3[0]))
        self.displacement3.append(int(actuator3[1]))
        self.cycle3 = int(actuator3[2])
        self.pressure4.append(int(actuator4[0]))
        self.displacement4.append(int(actuator4[1]))
        self.cycle4 = int(actuator4[2])
        self.line0.set_data(self.xdata, self.pressure1)
        self.line1.set_data(self.xdata, self.pressure2)
        self.line2.set_data(self.xdata, self.pressure3)
        self.line3.set_data(self.xdata, self.pressure4)
        self.line4.set_data(self.xdata, self.displacement1)
        self.line5.set_data(self.xdata, self.displacement2)
        self.line6.set_data(self.xdata, self.displacement3)
        self.line7.set_data(self.xdata, self.displacement4)
        if self.k < 49:
            self.ax1.set_ylim(min(self.pressure1)-1, max(self.pressure3) + 1)
            self.ax1.set_xlim(0, self.k+1)
            self.ax2.set_ylim(min(self.displacement1)-1, max(self.displacement3) + 1)
            self.ax2.set_xlim(0, self.k+1)
        elif self.k >= 49:
            self.ax1.set_ylim(min(self.pressure1[self.k-49:self.k])-1, max(self.pressure3[self.k-49:self.k]) + 1)
            self.ax1.set_xlim(self.xdata[self.k-49], self.xdata[self.k-1])
            self.ax2.set_ylim(min(self.displacement1[self.k-49:self.k])-1, max(self.displacement3[self.k-49:self.k]) + 1)
            self.ax2.set_xlim(self.xdata[self.k-49], self.xdata[self.k-1])
        self.k += 1




root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is a gui that prints to the monitor:

```
import Tkinter
import serial
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.arduinoData = serial.Serial('com5', 250000, timeout=0)

        frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)

        self.go = 0

        self.start = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Start", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.start.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.run = Tkinter.Button(self.start, text="RUN", bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.getData)
        self.run.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.stop_frame = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="STOP", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10 )
        self.stop_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.stop = Tkinter.Button(self.stop_frame, text="STOP", bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.stopTest)
        self.stop.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.fig = plt.Figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(211)
        self.line0, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line1, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line2, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line3, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(212)
        self.line4, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line5, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line6, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line7, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,master=master)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=4, padx=20, pady=20)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

    def getData(self):
        self.k = 0
        self.xdata = []
        self.pressure1 = []
        self.displacement1 = []
        self.cycle1 = []
        self.pressure2 = []
        self.displacement2 = []
        self.cycle2 = []
        self.pressure3 = []
        self.displacement3 = []
        self.cycle3 = []
        self.pressure4 = []
        self.displacement4 = []
        self.cycle4 = []
        self.arduinoData.flushInput()
        self.go = 1
        self.readData()

    def readData(self):
        if self.go == 1:
            self.xdata.append(self.k)
            while (self.arduinoData.inWaiting()==0):
                pass
            x = self.arduinoData.readline()
            strip_data = x.strip()
            split_data = x.split("|")
            actuator1 = split_data[0].split(".")
            actuator2 = split_data[1].split(".")
            actuator3 = split_data[2].split(".")
            actuator4 = split_data[3].split(".")
            self.pressure1.append(int(actuator1[0]))
            self.displacement1.append(int(actuator1[1]))
            self.cycle1 = int(actuator1[2])
            self.pressure2.append(int(actuator2[0]))
            self.displacement2.append(int(actuator2[1]))
            self.cycle2 = int(actuator2[2])
            self.pressure3.append(int(actuator3[0]))
            self.displacement3.append(int(actuator3[1]))
            self.cycle3 = int(actuator3[2])
            self.pressure4.append(int(actuator4[0]))
            self.displacement4.append(int(actuator4[1]))
            self.cycle4 = int(actuator4[2])
            self.printData()
            root.after(0, self.readData)


    def printData(self):
        print str(self.pressure1[self.k-1]) + " " + 
        str(self.displacement1[self.k-1]) + " " + str(self.cycle1) + " " + 
        str(self.pressure2[self.k-1]) + " " + str(self.displacement2[self.k-
        1]) + " " + str(self.cycle2) + " " + str(self.pressure3[self.k-1]) + 
        " " + str(self.displacement3[self.k-1]) + " " + str(self.cycle3) + " 
        " + str(self.pressure4[self.k-1]) + " " + 
        str(self.displacement4[self.k-1]) + " " + str(self.cycle4)

    def stopTest(self):
        self.arduinoData.write("<H>")
        self.go = 0


    def resetTest(self):
        self.k = 0
        self.xdata = []
        self.pressure1 = []
        self.displacement1 = []
        self.cycle1 = []
        self.pressure2 = []
        self.displacement2 = []
        self.cycle2 = []
        self.pressure3 = []
        self.displacement3 = []
        self.cycle3 = []
        self.pressure4 = []
        self.displacement4 = []
        self.cycle4 = []
        self.line1.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata1)
        self.line2.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata2)
        self.ax1.set_ylim(0,1)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(0,1)
        self.ax2.set_ylim(0,1)
        self.ax2.set_xlim(0,1)

    def start(self):
        self.xdata = []
        self.pressure1 = []
        self.displacement1 = []
        self.cycle1 = []
        self.pressure2 = []
        self.displacement2 = []
        self.cycle2 = []
        self.pressure3 = []
        self.displacement3 = []
        self.cycle3 = []
        self.pressure4 = []
        self.displacement4 = []
        self.cycle4 = []
        self.k = 0
        self.arduinoData.write("<L>")

root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

and here is an example arduino code:

```
int analog0 = 0;
int analog1 = 1;
int analog2 = 2;

int sensor0;
int sensor1;
int sensor2;

String pot0;
String pot1;
String Force;

int pot0holder;
int pot1holder;
String Forceholder;

unsigned long i = 0;
String Is;

int val = 0;

boolean Sensordata = false;
int cycles;

const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];
boolean newData = false;

unsigned long CurrentMillis = 0;
unsigned long PrintMillis = 0;
int PrintValMillis = 50;
unsigned long SensorMillis = 0;
int SensorValMillis = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(250000);
}

void loop()
{
  CurrentMillis = millis();
  recvWithStartEndMarkers();
  commands();
  sensordata();
}

void sensordata()
{
  if (CurrentMillis - SensorMillis >= SensorValMillis)
  {
    sensor0 = analogRead(analog0);
    pot0holder = sensor0;
    sensor1 = analogRead(analog1);
    pot1holder = sensor1;
    i += 1;
    String potcolumn = String(pot0holder) + "." + String(pot1holder) + "." +  String(i) + "|" + String(int(pot0holder)+30) + "." + String(int(pot1holder)+30) + "." +  String(i) + "|" + String(int(pot0holder)+60) + "." + String(int(pot1holder)+60) + "." +  String(i) + "|" + String(int(pot0holder)+90) + "." + String(int(pot1holder)+90) + "." +  String(i);
    Serial.println(potcolumn);
    SensorMillis += SensorValMillis;
   }
}

void recvWithStartEndMarkers()
{
    static boolean recvInProgress = false; //creates variable visible to only one function with boolean
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<'; //sets begin condition
    char endMarker = '>'; //sets end condition
    char rc; //sets variable type to char

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read(); //sets rc equal to serial value

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= numChars) {
                    ndx = numChars - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
        }
        else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
        }
    }
}

void commands()
{
  if (newData == true)
  {
    if (receivedChars[0] == 'T')
    {
      PrintValMillis = atoi(&receivedChars[1]); //atoi -> Converting strings to integer
    }
    else if (receivedChars[0] == 'S')
    {
      cycles = atoi(&receivedChars[1]);
      i = 0;
    }
        else if (receivedChars[0] == 'L')
    {
      val = atoi(&receivedChars[1]);
      i = 0;
    }
  }
  newData = false;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice any one has.

Comment: After profiling the code i found that over the first 300 iterations of the update equation in the graph it averages 0.0429900026321 seconds this should leave it with time to spare yet it still lags behind even though the graphing needs to only occur every .05 seconds

Comment: First you would need to find your bottleneck. Is it the reading of the data or the plotting? Then you could put them in separate processes where the reader feeds a pipe to the printer.

Comment: Additionally, you should optimize your code a bit: the printData-function can be accelerated by using `"sep".join([str1, str2, ...])` with sep being your white space.
Real-time matplot-plotting you should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874767/real-time-plotting-in-while-loop-with-matplotlib

Comment: over 300 iterations the average time that i found the code to execute is 0.040306673050 with the reading functionality taking 0.039366672834
and setting the line and axis data taking 0.000940000216
@RaJa

Comment: I was only using the printData function to see if i was able to read the data in fast enough. with the code that I posted i was able to read the data and print it fast enough then i wanted to see if i could graph the data after i knew that I could read and at least print it fast enough. Sorry for not explaining that well @RaJa

Answer (score 0):

So your reading process takes most of the time. I would put the reading in a separate task and do the evaluation/splitting of the data in the main (drawing)-process. Unfortunately, I am not a tkinter user, so I have written this without any special gui-framework. But I think you can adapt this to your needs.

That would look like that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import multiprocessing as mp
import time


# global variables
fig = plt.figure(1)
# first sub-plot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
line1, = ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
ax1.grid()
xdata1, ydata1 = [], []
# second sub-plot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
line2, = ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
ax2.grid()
xdata2, ydata2 = [], []

# the multiprocessing queue
q = mp.Queue()

# data generator in separate process
# here would be your arduino data reader
def dataGen(output):
    for x in range(50):
        output.put((x, np.sin(x)))

# update first subplot
def update1(data):
    # update the data
    t, y = data
    xdata1.append(t)
    ydata1.append(y)
    xmin, xmax = ax1.get_xlim()
    ymin, ymax = ax1.get_ylim()

    if t >= xmax:
        ax1.set_xlim(xmin, 2*xmax)
    if y >= ymax:
        ax1.set_ylim(ymin, 2*ymax)
    if y <= ymin:
        ax1.set_ylim(2*ymin, ymax)
    line1.set_data(xdata1, ydata1)

    return line1,

# update second subplot
def update2(data):
    # update the data
    t, y = data
    xdata2.append(t)
    ydata2.append(y)
    xmin, xmax = ax2.get_xlim()
    ymin, ymax = ax2.get_ylim()

    if t >= xmax:
        ax2.set_xlim(xmin, 2*xmax)
    if y >= ymax:
        ax2.set_ylim(ymin, 2*ymax)
    if y <= ymin:
        ax2.set_ylim(2*ymin, ymax) 
    line2.set_data(xdata2, ydata2)

    return line2,

# called at each drawing frame
def run(data):
    # get data from queue, which is filled in separate process, blocks until
    # data is available
    data = q.get(block=True, timeout=.5)
    # put here your variable separation
    data1 = (2*data[0], 3*data[1])
    data2 = (data[0], data[1])
    #provide the data to the plots
    a = update1(data1)
    b = update2(data2)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    return a+b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # count of reader processes
    n_proc = 1
    # setup workers
    pool = [mp.Process(target=dataGen, args=(q,)) for x in range(n_proc)]
    for p in pool:
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    # wait a few sec for the process to become alive
    time.sleep(3)

    # start your drawing
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, frames=60, blit=True, interval=10,
                                  repeat=False)
    plt.show()

    print('done')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @RaJa im still new to multiprocessing and threading so I'll be working on trying to get this to intake the arduino and plot

Comment: The issue I am having is that the dataGen function produces all of the data at the same time and then those are sent to the other functions once that is complete then the program proceeds to graph. I need to be able to take in one point at a time and then update the graph. This needs to be done ideally in parallel where the new arduino data modifies the instance variables im using and then the graph sees that new data has been added and adds the point to the graph.

Comment: `data = q.get(block=True)` actually waits until data is available. So the graph does not update, unless new data is available. Next: queues are first in, first out. So what the reader sends, gets plotted directly - Point by point. But the data sent by the reader has not to go directly to the graphs. You can add another step, processing the data and this to the graph. You can also send packages of data through the queue. Or the reader does all the processing itself. Currently, I do not see the problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

My question is very similar with yours.
I need to get data from a profi-bus network every 80ms, and I want the data to be plotted while sampling.

I used multiprocessing to solve the problem.The Pipe was used for communication between two processes.
When the Plotter gets data from Collector, and it is going to plot something, the Plotter will send a message to the Collector. and then the Collector will stop sending the data and put the data into a list.
when plotter done its job, it tells the collector that 'now you can send data', the collector then send the data and clear the list.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from random import random

class DataGennerator(object):
    """docstring for DataGennerator"""
    def __init__(self, data_pipe):
        super(DataGennerator, self).__init__()
        print('Data Gennerator Init...')
        self.data_buffer = []
        self.t = 0
        self.start_time = 0
        self.data_pipe = data_pipe
        self.plot_inprogess = False
        self.data_ready = False
 
    def run(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        for i in range(0, 400):
            self.loop_cycle()
        print('Total Time:', time.time()-self.start_time)
        print('Run completion......')

    def loop_cycle(self):
        self.t = time.time()-self.start_time
        new_data = [time.time()-self.start_time, np.sin(self.t), np.cos(2*self.t), np.cos(self.t*4), random()]
        self.send_data(new_data)
        time.sleep(0.08)

    def send_data(self, new_data):
        if self.plot_inprogess or not self.data_ready:
            self.data_buffer.append(new_data)
            self.data_ready = True
            # Wait 1ms to read plotter's msg
            if self.data_pipe.poll(0.0001):
                self.plot_inprogess = self.data_pipe.recv()
        else:
            self.data_pipe.send(self.data_buffer)
            self.data_buffer = []
            self.data_ready = False

# Function to collect data by using DataGennerator
def get_data(data_pipe):
    dg = DataGennerator(data_pipe)
    dg.run()
    data_pipe.send('EXIT')
    print('>>> Finished')


# use plotter_pipe to communicate with data collector
# and when get data from the collector, updata the figure
def updata_plot(plotter_pipe, plot_inprogess=True):
    plot_inprogess = True
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=1, figsize=(6,8), sharex=True)
    fig.set_tight_layout(True)
    styles = ['rs-', 'gs-', 'bs-', 'ro-', 'go-', 'bo-']*10
    lines = []
    for index, name in enumerate(['sin(t)', 'cos(t)', 'cos(2t)', 'random']):
        line, = ax[index].plot([],[], styles[index],label=name, markersize=4, markerfacecolor='w')
        ax[index].set_ylabel(name, color=styles[index][0], fontweight='bold')
        lines.append(line)
    ax[-1].set_xlabel('Time /s')
    fig.align_ylabels(ax)
    plt.ion()
    plt.show(block=False)
    plt.draw()

    # Read the 1st data package and convert it to Numpy Array
    data_array = np.array(plotter_pipe.recv())

    while True:
        try:
            # Read data_buffer sent by Data Collector
            data_buffer = plotter_pipe.recv()   #[ [data1], [data2]...]
            # If the DataCollector says EXIT, then break the while loop
            if data_buffer == 'EXIT': break
            # Raise a flag to indicate that Plot is in progress
            plotter_pipe.send(True)
            # Append data_buffer to Data Array
            data_array = np.append(data_array, np.array(data_buffer), axis=0)
            for i in range(0, 4):
                lines[i].set_xdata(data_array[:,0])
                lines[i].set_ydata(data_array[:,i+1])
                ax[i].relim()
                ax[i].autoscale_view()
            fig.canvas.draw()
            plt.pause(0.001)
            # Tell data collector that Plot has been finished
            plotter_pipe.send(False)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        finally:
            pass
    print('>>> Stop receiving data')
    data_content = '\n'.join([', '.join(map(str,data_line)) for data_line in data_array])
    with open('data.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        f.write('time, xx, yy, zz, bb\n')
        f.writelines(data_content)
    plt.show(block=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    plot_inprogess = True
    data_pipe, plotter_pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe(True)
    P1 = Process(target=get_data   , args=(data_pipe,))
    P2 = Process(target=updata_plot, args=(plotter_pipe,))
    P1.start()
    P2.start()
    P1.join()
    P2.join()
```