# Python pandas create a bitmap from a timeseries object

Tags: python, pandas, bitmap, time-series

I am looking for a way to create a bitmap image from a timeseries.

The timeseries is per minute for one year.
It has 24x60 = 1440 entries per day.

I need a bitmap per year black and white color 365 x 1440

How to create a bitmap is clear due to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434583/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-draw-an-image-from-discrete-pixel-values-in-python)

My main issue is to create a matrix 1440 x 365 from a minute timeseries...

Thx

hugo

Answer (score 0):

you can use scipy

```
import numpy as np

day1 = np.random.random(100)
day2 = np.random.random(100)
day3 = np.random.random(100)
day4 = np.random.random(100)


img = [day1,day2,day3,day4]



import scipy.misc
scipy.misc.imsave('outfile.bmp', np.array(img))
```

alternative, you can transpose it, so your data are in columns

```
scipy.misc.imsave('outfileT.bmp', np.array(img).T)
```

Comment: Hi Mohammed, the bitmap part was already clear sory for not stating that to clearly, how to shape the one year timeseries with per minute data into a array or matrix is my challenge... i am now investigating pandas.pivot_table()