# Best way to draw pixel in python

Tags: python

I was wondering, what is the simplest way to draw a pixel in python with x and y values?

Comment: This may be more than a pixel but it still draws a pixel: `print('.')`

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434583/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-draw-an-image-from-discrete-pixel-values-in-python

Answer (score 10):

Probably the simplest way is use [PIL](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm) (Python Imaging Library) which makes it possible in 4 lines:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageColor

im = Image.new('1', (1,1)) # create the Image of size 1 pixel 
im.putpixel((0,0), ImageColor.getcolor('black', '1')) # or whatever color you wish

im.save('simplePixel.png') # or any image format
```

The documentation shows lots of other ways to customize it http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#examples.

Comment: I would suggest [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/4.1.1) which it's a fork of PIL but maintaned by Plone team. Otherwise, +1 because your solution still so easy with a short code.

Comment: firstly, what does the 'RGBA' value do?

Comment: second of all, how would i do this for multiple random positions?

Comment: @AleKid, you're right, `'RGBA'` is unnecessary in this example, the parameters for a new [Image.new(mode, size) ⇒ image](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#functions), defined as: `'mode of an image defines the type and depth of a pixel in the image: RGBA (4x8-bit pixels, true colour with transparency mask)'`I just took it arbitrarily from this list [concepts.htm#mode](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes), more simple would be use `'1 (1-bit pixels, black and white, stored with one pixel per byte)'`, I updated this in the answer

Comment: Must i save the pixel? I am trying to draw many random pixels, and store their position so i can move them later, to simulate air movement. There doesn't happen to be any way to store the pixel position using PIL? thank you @downshift.