# Why is PIL.ImageColor.getcolor() only returning white or black?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have this code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageColor
i = Image.new('1', (1, 1))
i.putpixel((0, 0), ImageColor.getcolor('black','1'))
i.save('simplePixel.png')
```

taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190901/best-way-to-draw-pixel-in-python/44191162#44191162).

Running this produces a 1 pixel image that is black. If I change the color to red, for example:

```
ImageColor.getcolor('red','1')
```

I get a white pixel instead of red. I've tried yellow, green blue; they all result in a white pixel. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the wrong mode:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageColor
i = Image.new('RGB', (1, 1))
i.putpixel((0, 0), ImageColor.getcolor('red','RGB'))
i.save('simplePixel.png')
```

I replaced the `'1'` with `'RGB'` and now it works.